# How Does System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger.EventName Efficiently Work With Or Without Reflection?

Tags: .net, wpf, reflection, expression-blend

I see that the [System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger.EventName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger.eventname%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) takes in a string.  Also, I would imagine they need to hook up to that event via reflection.

But reflection has a bit of a bad name especially with performance, so are there performance issues with the [System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726539%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx).  So is the code below the most efficient way to hook up to an event and is Expression Blend's SDK doing something special?

```
public class EventToCommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommand), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnEventHandlerChanged));

    public static string GetEventName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(EventNameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEventName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EventNameProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnEventHandlerChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        var info = objType.GetEvent((string)args.NewValue);

        MethodInfo handler = typeof(EventToCommand).GetMethod("OnEventHandlerRaised", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EventToCommand));
        Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(info.EventHandlerType, o, handler);
        MethodInfo addHandler = info.GetAddMethod();
        object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };
        addHandler.Invoke(obj, addHandlerArgs);
    }

    private void OnEventHandlerRaised(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Is it a unique instance?
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    Guid value = Guid.NewGuid();
    public EventToCommand()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I provided in my question is definitely the slower way to do it.  The better way is to use the following and not use invoke:

```
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    var info = objType.GetEvent((string)args.NewValue);

    MethodInfo handler = typeof(EventToCommand).GetMethod("OnEventHandlerRaised", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EventToCommand));
    Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(info.EventHandlerType, o, handler);
    info.AddEventHandler(obj, d);
```

The above method is a lot faster than using Reflection's invoke.  You can then remove it via info.RemoveEventHandler(obj, d).

Answer (score 0):

Since those are routed events I don't think that reflection is used in order to register to the events. Same as in data binding and dependency properties - it's not done through reflection.